# How to use std::shared_ptr and std::map correctly

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to implement some sort of simulation game on a 2D grid.

I have 8 different basic graphics for tiles and want to hold pointer to the image data in a map, so I can later access them by the type of the tile (Land, Water ...) which is defined as enum (key for the map).

I have an `image` class which holds the header of the image and the actual data stored in a `std::vector<char>`. The image class loads those images and returns a `std::vector<std::shared_pointer<image>>` to my GUI class. Since im working with Qt I want to store shared pointer to `QPixmap` to draw it later on my map.

My map looks like :

`std::map<TERRAIN_TYPE, std::shared_ptr<QPixmap>> m_terrain_type_to_pixmap;`

I generate my QPixmap like this :

```
std::shared_ptr<QPixmap> pixmap_deep_water = std::make_shared<QPixmap>(m_tga_terrain_images[0]->pixel_data().data()); // pixel_data() gets the vector of bytes
```

I insert it to the map like this:

```
m_terrain_type_to_pixmap.insert(std::pair<TERRAIN_TYPE, std::shared_ptr<QPixmap>>(TERRAIN_TYPE::DEEP_WATER, pixmap_deep_water));
```

I'm accessing elements int this way:

```
auto test = m_terrain_type_to_pixmap.find(m_presenter.model.m_world.m_map[0].m_terrain_type)->second;
```

And here is my problem:

After I retrieved an element from my map, the pointer doesn't point to any data (according to the debugger and the screen is filled with only white tiles). Before I retrieved the pointer everything seems fine in the debugger, but the elements of the map that got retrieved seem to 'loose' their data.

Comment: How does `QPixmap` store its data? If it holds a pointer to external data `m_tga_terrain_images[0]->pixel_data().data()` may have changed or become invalidated.

Comment: There is no problem here with shared_ptr and map.

Comment: either the data is never there and `pixmap_deep_water` doesn't contain data to start with or `m_terrain_type_to_pixmap.find` is returning `m_terrain_type_to_pixmap.end()` and your program has undefined behaviour

Comment: The pointer was null before the map, my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QPixmap has no constructor taking a pointer to (unsigned) char.

```
std::shared_ptr<QPixmap> pixmap_deep_water = std::make_shared<QPixmap>(m_tga_terrain_images[0]->pixel_data().data()); // pixel_data() gets the vector of bytes
```

You should declare QPixmap and invoke `loadFromData()`.

```
QPixmap pixmap;  // or std::shared_ptr<QPixmap>
std::vector<unsigned char>& imgdata=m_tga_terrain_images[0]->pixel_data();
pixmap.loadFromData(imgdata.data(), imgdata.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html),

> QPixmap objects can be passed around by value since the QPixmap class
> uses implicit data sharing. For more information, see the Implicit
> Data Sharing documentation. QPixmap objects can also be streamed.

You make your life easier by **not** doing shared_ptr with it; you should also double-check after creating it from your tga data vector, that the resulting pixmap is valid. You might be seeing a problem when accessing it from the map, that really happens earlier. (And, if you're doing Qt, it's probably easier to use QRC instead of manually bunging together your resources as vectors of chars -- thats what the other answer is also getting it).

Comment: I oversaw that paragraph in the documentation - thanks a lot! You're probably right, that I should use QRC, but this is an assingment for a programming class and it is mandatory to read the images manually and store the data in an own data structure.